# Delete all snapshots over 30 days old

Tags: vmware-esxi, snapshot, powercli

I'm currently using VMware 5.1 and looking for a method to keep snapshots that users create from becoming too old. Is there any tool inside of VMware that allows you to manage snapshots (or possibly a method to script this)?

Ideally I'd like to delete any snapshots that become over a month old automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this easily with powercli, as there is a 'remove-shapshot' cmdlet:

```
$oneMonthAgo = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
Get-VM | Foreach-Object {
Get-Snapshot -VM $_ | Foreach-Object {
if($_.Created -lt $oneMonthAgo) {
Remove-Snapshot $_ -Confirm -WhatIf
}}}
```

I put the `-Confirm` and `-WhatIf` in there because `Remove-Snapshot` could potentially do a lot of damage -- you want to make sure it's targeting the right snapshots before taking those parameters out.

Comment: Shouldn't instead of -lt it be greater than in your code snippet? Aside from that however this is exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: Logically you would think that, but it compares the dates numerically, so earlier = lower value.

Answer (score 1):

```
$oneMonthAgo = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
Get-VM | Foreach-Object {
Get-Snapshot -VM $_ | Foreach-Object {
if($_.Created -lt $oneMonthAgo) {
Remove-Snapshot $_ -Confirm:$false
}}}
```

I guess the above script will do and yes add it to task scheduler which will still ease of the work. Recommend to delete the snapshots that are 3 days old.